# JQuery Autocomplete not working on button/link click

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, myfaces, trinidad

I have below code, which is calling jquery JSON autocomplete on button click. It is working as expected only for the very first time, autocomplete is called when i click the commandlink, but next time the autocomplete is triggered when i started typing in the text box (before i click on the command link). It works again when i refresh the page- autocomplete called only when link clicked.

```
<ui:component>
    <tr:panelGroupLayout>
        <tr:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}">
        </tr:inputText>

    <tr:commandLink id="idGlobalTrigger" partialSubmit="true">
        <tr:image source="/resources/images/tick_light.gif"></tr:image>
    </tr:commandLink>
    </tr:panelGroupLayout>
    <script>
    $("#idGlobalTrigger").click(function() {
    /*text box id   */                  
        var jqueryObj = "#"+"#{id}";    
        $(jqueryObj).autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {                      
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/GlobalServlet",
                        data : {
                            term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(
                                data) {
                            response(data);
                        },
                        error : function(
                                XMLHttpRequest,
                                textStatus,
                                errorThrown) {
                            // alert('Error1'+textStatus +textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            $(jqueryObj).focus();
            $(jqueryObj).autocomplete("search");
         });
    </script>
</ui:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinitialize the autocomplete on select event. This resolves my issue.

```
$(jqueryObj).on("autocompleteselect", function(event,ui) {          
        $(jqueryObj).autocomplete({
            source : null,
            response: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.content.push({value:'', id:0, label:''});
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the auto complete logic in function and call the function on document.ready

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    autocomplete()
    });

function autoComplete(){
//logic here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be compounding your listeners. In other words, calling the autoComplete function on click instead of on page load (which is the best practice as already mentioned) means that another identical listener is added every time a user clicks the element.

You will need to clear any previous listeners every time the element is clicked to keep them from "piling up". Try updating your code with this snippet:

```
 $("#idGlobalTrigger").off("click").on("click",function() {
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this did not worked.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation to see if there is a "re-initialize" function you could call?

Comment: In documentation i see these options, which i thought may related to reinitialize "destroy,disable,enable,instance". I used one or more combinations of these, before i start the autocomplete or after the autocomplete, but nothing helped me.

Comment: Why can't you initialize on page load like Ram mentioned? Is the element loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @BWDesin, i did not understand that concept. I have to do autocomplete call only on a button click.